# Laravel paginate order by

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

What should I do to pass the values ​​that you order by in patinate?

routes.php

```
$ondata = DB::table('official_news') -> orderBy('created_date', 'desc') -> get() -> paginate(7);
return View::make('main',array('ondata' => $ondata));
```

error

```
Call to a member function paginate() on a non-object
```

I need your help

Answer (score 62, accepted):

This should do the trick:

`$ondata = DB::table('official_news')->orderBy('created_date', 'desc')->paginate(7);`

Comment: @ErfanAhmedEmon yes it can even with relations. For example: Auth::user()->notifications()->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->paginate(25);

Answer (score 33):

It will be better if you order it by the id because it is going to be faster from the database.

```
$posts = Post::orderBy('id', 'desc')->paginate(6);
```

https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/combining-paginate-with-orderby

It works fine for Laravel 5.1.

Answer (score 2):

You can use something like this in your controller file.

```
$transactions = Transaction::orderBy('name')->paginate(10);
return view('index', compact('transactions'));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using **scope**

```
 public function scopeSearch($query, $term)
    {
        $term = "%$term%";
        $query->where(function ($query) use ($term) {
            $query->where('name', 'like', $term)
                .............
                ..............
                ->orWhere('pan_number', 'like', $term);
        })->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC');
    }
```