# how to use pagination in groupby & orderby clause for fetching records in laravel by year wise

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

```
$newsYearCount = news::paginate(5)->groupBy(function($date) {
                      return Carbon::parse($date->created_at)->format('Y'); //
                  });
```

i want to use order By for above code and also it just group By 5 records, but i want a records like firstly it should group By and then apply pagination.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Currently, pagination operations that use a groupBy statement cannot
>   be executed efficiently by Laravel. If you need to use a groupBy with
>   a paginated result set, it is recommended that you query the database
>   and create a paginator manually.

check here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/pagination#basic-usage

check this for order by : https://stackoverflow.com/a/19885982/2815635

Comment: can you suggest a code from which i will get results yearwise with pagination?