# laravel 5.4 pagination links() method returns empty html

Tags: php, pagination, eloquent, laravel-5.4

laravel 5.4 pagination links() method returns empty html string :

controller :

```
$articleBlogs = ArticleBlog::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->paginate(10);
```

view :

```
{{ $articleBlogs->links() }}
```

output of : dd($articleBlogs)

```
LengthAwarePaginator {#216 ▼
  #total: 3
  #lastPage: 1
  #items: Collection {#211 ▼
    #items: array:3 [▶]
  }
  #perPage: 10
  #currentPage: 1
  #path: "http://localhost/Asmoza/prestakpi-laravel/public/blog"
  #query: []
  #fragment: null
  #pageName: "page"
}
```

output of : dd($articleBlogs->links());

```
 HtmlString {#208 ▼
    #html: ""
 }
```

I tried :

```
php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-pagination
```

as described in the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/pagination#customizing-the-pagination-view), no effect

Any ideas ?

**EDIT :**

```
{{ $articleBlogs->render() }}
```

is same result

Comment: maybe you have only one page?
have you tried to set paginate(1)

Comment: Check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19885907/laravel-paginate-order-by

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution :
if paginator has only one page to show, it generates an empty links string.

Answer (score 1):

You paginate 10, you don't have enough results to paginate, try by 2 and add more rows to ArticleBlog.